# Cancelled Careers account still gets email ; no unsubscribe option

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I purchased a StackOverflow Careers account, and then canceled it (I got a job!). However, this morning I got a couple of messages regarding the service. I should no longer be on the recipient list. Also, the email has no "unsubscribe" link, which it arguably should...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed - you are now removed from the email list.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, yes, that's definitely an error -- the email *should* have only gone to active paid subscribers!